# Weird OutOfMemoryError when loading view pager

Tags: android

I created an activity that contain a view pager using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. The app crash immediately when launch this activity with an `OutOfMemmoryError` below. Please help to point me which mistake. I spend several hours but can't find myself.

```
02-07 23:04:58.187 16037-16037/com.makeit.lite E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 34831542 byte allocation with 16765168 free bytes and 31MB until OOM
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:687)
    at java.io.Writer.append(Writer.java:198)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
    at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:343)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:61)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.-wrap0(RuntimeInit.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:86)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Here is the source code of the activity and view pager:

1. Initialize the view pager:

```
fragments.add(new MonthFragment());
fragments.add(new MonthFragment());
fragments.add(new MonthFragment());
fragments.add(new MonthFragment());
fragments.add(new MonthFragment());
fragments.add(new MonthFragment());
setContentView(R.layout.activity_date_picker);
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
viewPager.setAdapter(new MonthAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

2. The adapter:

```
class MonthAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MonthAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
}
```

3. Fragment with empty layout

```
public class MonthFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_month, container);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:orientation="vertical">
>
>     <Button
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="test"/>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_month, container, false); try this instead of inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_month, container);

Comment: So far I could not find anything that might cause OOM in the code you provided but are you using an HD image in your layout?

Comment: do you use large heap size?

Comment: What is the layout of MonthFragment ? Most probably there could be a large image(s) behind the OOM error.

Comment: @Nguyen Minh Binh try to set offscreenpagelimit with viewPager,

Comment: OMG. Many thanks @JadavLalit. This is the mistake that I can not see in half day. It works now.

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh youre' welcome

Comment: please reduce image size just

Comment: The crash caused by I make a mistake when loading the view layout. I didn't use any image, No need to change `offscreenpagelimit`, no need to change heap size. The comment of @JadavLalit is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The `inflate` call is adding the new MonthFragment to the container passed in.

Also the fragments.add() is doing the same thing.  This is creating an incorrect graph, which is causing the memory to run out.

Using `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_month, container, false);` Inflates the xml, but does not attach it to the view.  Meaning the fragments.add() only creates one copy of the fragment, and everything works.